# New CXS update issue - DirectAdmin

Tags: linux, centos, anti-virus

I have problem with new version of CXS.

When we want to upgrade it we had problem with restricted file (but we passed it). Now when I want to upgrade from DirectAdmin panel we got error

```
Can't locate Linux/Inotify2.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/cxs /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/sbin/cxs line 232.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/cxs line 232.
```

Note: Through CLI it was possible to update CXS but in DirectAdmin panel we have that notification about missing Inotify2.pm module (perl have installed that module - checked by `cpan -i Linux::Inotify2`)

What can cause that problem? Or what more information is required for you to know?

OS: `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`

Answer (score 0):

cd /usr/src

wget https://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/Linux/Linux-Inotify2-2.1.tar.gz

tar -axf Linux-Inotify2-2.1.tar.gz

cd Linux-Inotify2-2.1

perl Makefile.PL

make

make install

You can run this commands for install Linux-Inotiy or run this command to install via yum

yum -y install epel-release -y

yum install perl-Linux-Inotify2 -y